# division of polynomials

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, fields

Consider the set of polynomials $k[x^1,\cdots,x^n]$ over any field $k$. Now, given $p,q\in k[x^1,\cdots,x^n]$, what are the necessary and suficient conditions in order to q divide p? That is: $\exists r \in k[x^1,\cdots,x^n]$ such that $p = rq$. I know that necessary condition is that every root of $q$ is also a root to $p$, but I don't know if this is a sufficient condition since I only can prove it when the field is algebraic close $k=\bar{k}$.

Is this even a good question to be done? If not please let me know why

Comment: The ring of polynomials over a field is a unique factorization domain, and so divisibility is just a matter of the exponents in the factorizations into irreducibles.